# redraw using drawRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a subclass of UIView in which it has a drawRect in it. It basically draws a line and an image.
I have drawn this in viewDidLoad, but need to change the layout when the view changes to landscape. How can I redraw this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the view's `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`. The view will call `[self setNeedsDisplay]` whenever its bounds change. You will only have to resize the view as needed.

Comment: you mean set it in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation? I also have changed the UIView's y origin, however it doesn't change it

Comment: You should resize the view when appropriate, so I guess `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is a good candidate. Just do `myView.frame = ...` there. Changing the view's `frame` origin doesn't really change its `bounds` (only the view's position is affected). Changing the view's `frame` size does.